# Append HTML to a DIV in a forum

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

This is yet another question about appending HTML (I have seen another questions already answered but I can't make it work on my own).

I need to add a couple of HTML lines inside a DIV in the form of a DL. To put it context, it's a (spanish) forum where I want to add extra info under every user in a thread.

Take this page as an example: http://www.antronio.cl/threads/comunidad-steam-antronio.1127070/page-222, each user has its avatar, a nick name, a secondary nick name and under all that a box with extra info. This is the box I want to modify.

The box is a DIV called "extraUserInfo" and every line on that box is a DL called "pairsJustified". I want to add a DL at the begining with text on it like the ones already there, but I can't make it work.

This is my manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts":  [{
    "js":   ["js\/medallas.js"],
    "matches":  ["http://www.antronio.cl/threads/*/*/"]
}],
"description":  "medallas para usuarios",
"name":         "medallas",
"version":      "1",
"permissions": ["tabs","http://www.antronio.cl/threads/*/*/"]
}
```

and my "medallas.js"

```
var dl  = document.createElement("dl");
dl.setAttribute("class","pairsJustified");
dl.innerHTML = "<dt>Status:</dt><dd>OK</dd>";
document.getElementById("extraUserInfo").appendChild(dl);
```

I'm new to this and actually trying to learn with this extension. Maybe even my folder structure is wrong

```
/medallas/
  manifest.json
  /js/
    medallas.js
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the HTML of one post.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/c9xTKn9w

Comment: `"js\/medallas.js"` should be `"js/medallas.js"`.

Comment: I've tried that way. Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is there is no element with id `extraUserInfo`. They are using a class. You'll want to use `getElementsByClassName` and iterate over the NodeList. Something similar to this should get you started.

```
var extraUserInfos = document.getElementsByClassName("extraUserInfo");
for (var i = 0; i < extraUserInfos.length; ++i) {
    var item = extraUserInfos[i];
    var dl  = document.createElement("dl");
    dl.setAttribute("class","pairsJustified");
    dl.innerHTML = "<dt>Status:</dt><dd>OK</dd>";
    item.appendChild(dl);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and still doesn't work. I look at the code and it seems right, I don't see why it shouldn't work. Maybe I'm loading thje extension in the wrong way or I'm missing something. What do you think?

Comment: You need to start debugging step by step. Add an `alert('running');` to the top of the content script. Does the alert trigger when you load the page? If not than the match pattern is probably wrong.

Comment: That did it. The alert didn't trigger so it was actually a 'match' problem. I just used "<all_urls>" and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Jojondro You probably _really, really_ don't want to use `<all_urls>` for this. Try `*://www.antronio.cl/threads/*`

Comment: I had trouble using an exact pattern for this but now it works, thanks!. <all_urls> is gone.

Answer (score 0):

From the source on the site you mentioned the "extraUserInfo" is a class not an id.

You would want to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("extraUserInfo")
```

however this will return an array of all elements that match this.  To handle this you will need to loop through the array one at a time.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("extraUserInfo");
for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

  // place your logic here for each item.

    var dl  = document.createElement("dl");
    dl.setAttribute("class","pairsJustified");
    dl.innerHTML = "<dt>Status:</dt><dd>OK</dd>";
    items[i].appendChild(dl);
}
```

fyi: getElementById  will only return the first matched element, (id attributes are supposed to be unique)

hope this helps

more info: [getElementsByClassName](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname)

edit:

since the page utilizes jQuery you can place the code inside the jQuery doc ready event and you can even use jquery to append the elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.extraUserInfo').each(function(){
        $('<dl class="pairsJustified"><dt>Status:</dt><dd>OK</dd></dl>').appendTo(this)
    })
});
```

Comment: I just tried this and still doesn't work. I look at the code and it seems right, I don't see why it shouldn't work. Maybe I'm loading thje extension in the wrong way or I'm missing something. What do you think?

Comment: Looks like the page is wired up to use jQuery,  try placing the code inside a document.ready event


$(document).ready(function(){
  // Code Here.
});

This will ensure that the code will run after the page is loaded.

Comment: After re-reading your question it hit me that your talking about a Google browser extension. It looks like you will need to find the current window, and then execute the code inside a executeScript function.  I'm not familiar with these extensions, but here is where I found some code that searches for anchor elements using a extension the sample is called "broken links" found on this page [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples), this may lead you to what your looking for, if not maybe one of the other samples will

Comment: The content_script tag in the manifest is used to inject the code. executeScript isn't needed.